# When i create a form angular2 error is show cannot find name "product"?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

- First of all i am a learner of angular 2
  I am follow to this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_forms.htm 
  I have created to all These  file and code.
- first file name 'products.ts'
  code :-

  export class Product { 
    constructor ( 
    public productid: number, 
    public productname: string ,

  ) {  } 
  }

  - second file name 
        'product-form.component.ts' 
            code :-

    ```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { IProduct } from './products';
        import { ProductService } from '../products.service';

        @Component ({
           selector: 'product-form',
           templateUrl: './DEMO/product-form.component.html'
        })

        export class ProductFormComponent {
           model = new Product(2,'ProductA');
        }
    ```
- thread file name

  'product-form.component.html'
          code :-

  ```
      <div class = "container">
          <h1>Product Form</h1>
          <form>
             <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "productid">ID</label>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "productid" required
                   [(ngModel)] = "model.productid" name = "id">
             </div>

             <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "name">Name</label>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "name"
                   [(ngModel)] = "model.productname" name = "name">
             </div>
          </form>
       </div>
  ```

  - Now when i run URL http://localhost:4200/
  - Cannot GET / blank page show on browser
  - Visual Studio Code editor problem error is show 'cannot find name "product"'

Answer (score 1):

problem is here

```
export class ProductFormComponent {
       model = new Product(2,'ProductA');
    }
```

You did not import `Product` class

Comment: where place add this import class please tell me file name and code

Comment: in your "ProductFormComponent"  component

Comment: I have added this code import { Product } from './products';   in product.service.ts file  Thank to siddharth sahu now it is working fine and show

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned above the tutorial, **In step 3,** you did not add the code 2nd line

`import { Product } from './products';`